# SwiftUI: Why is second alert not showing?

Tags: swiftui, alert

In the following simple example, why is Alert 2 not showing up?

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var showingOtherButton = false
    @State private var showingAlert1 = false
    @State private var showingAlert2 = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Group {
            if showingOtherButton {
                Button("Show Alert 2") {
                    showingAlert2 = true
                }
                .alert(isPresented: $showingAlert2) {
                    print("Alert 2 should be shown")
                    return Alert(title: Text("Alert 2"), dismissButton: .default(Text("Ok")))
                }
            } else {
                Button("Show other Button") {
                    self.showingOtherButton = true
                }
                
                Button("Show Alert 1") {
                    showingAlert1 = true
                }
            }
        }
        .alert(isPresented: $showingAlert1) {
            Alert(title: Text("Alert 1"), dismissButton: .default(Text("OK")))
        }
    }
}
```

Placing the alert 1 modifier onto the "Show Alert 1" button directly makes it work, but I don't understand why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second alert should go in the same place as the first - attached to the `Group` view, not to the `Button`:

```swift
Group {
    if showingOtherButton {
        Button("Show Alert 2") {
            showingAlert2 = true
        }
    } else {
        Button("Show other Button") {
            self.showingOtherButton = true
        }
        
        Button("Show Alert 1") {
            showingAlert1 = true
        }
    }
}
.alert(isPresented: $showingAlert1) {
    Alert(title: Text("Alert 1"), dismissButton: .default(Text("OK")))
}
.alert(isPresented: $showingAlert2) {
    print("Alert 2 should be shown")
    return Alert(title: Text("Alert 2"), dismissButton: .default(Text("Ok")))
}
```

Comment: Yes, but why? Sometimes it seems more convenient to have the alert modifier on a nested view.

Comment: @Newton Conceptually, an iOS Alert belongs to the entire view. It completely interrupts the app flow, and the user can't continue without responding. If you want a popover on a nested subview, you can implement that. But iOS built-in alerts are a full-screen thing. You can read https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/windows_and_screens/getting_the_user_s_attention_with_alerts_and_action_sheets or https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/views/alerts/

Comment: I think this doesn't work. Other questions suggest that only one of the multiple alerts you attach to a single view will work (the last one).

Comment: @Azurlake, you are right. I observed that the parent alert overrides all the child alerts. So all the buttons should have their own alerts. And one should not put an alert on the parent view if they have alerts on the child view, because then it will override all the child view alerts.